# Global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, globals

I don't consider myself a highly skilled javascript developer, but I thought I got one thing right for sure: don't create global variables unless you really have to.

I've been learning `angularjs` lately and discovered one strange thing, almost everywhere in code samples for angular you can find constructions like the following.

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Phone',
  function($scope, Phone) {
    $scope.phones = Phone.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);
```

Source: official example app https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js

So I assumed I might be missing/misunderstanding something. Any thoughts except "since it's demo code, they don't care"?

Comment: @kdgregory: you may consider promoting your comment to an answer, since it actually answers the question.

Comment: @MainMa - done, although I think it would be better just to delete the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's demo code. If you want to read it from the Angular developers, go [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) and scroll down until you see

> In practice, you will not want to have your controller functions in the global namespace.